# Logo file size for multiple uses in web app

Tags: uploading, logos

The web app I work on currently has users upload different logo files for each product use--favicon, site logo, print logo, etc. We want to change this so users upload one file that can be used in all cases. I don't have a strong graphic design or visual design background and am struggling to figure out what size file we should ask users to upload for all these uses. My internet searches have only turned up best dimensions for specific use cases.

Comment: Have you confirmed that this is what your users want? I wonder, because the favicon is very often not the same as the company logo (for example, Google's favicon is a simple "G" instead of the full "Google" logo illegibly squished into a 16x16px square). Could you instead consider an option that says something like "[×] Use this logo file as my favicon also"?

Comment: I think you should reconsider this. How often are people going to change the files? My guess is not very often. So the impact of the effort needed to find/create and upload multiple files is smaller than the impact of having wrong or deformed images and not being able to change that.

Answer (score -1):

OK, so if your server is based on NodeJS, you can try out the [RealFaviconGenerator API](https://realfavicongenerator.net/api/). The NodeJS plugin can be found here: [RealFaviconGenerator NodeJS](https://github.com/RealFaviconGenerator/rfg-api).

I also found this really neat NodeJS module called `favicons` ([repo](https://github.com/itgalaxy/favicons))

Just remember that you'll need to make sure to communicate to the user that there's a minimum image size of `260x260px`.

Hopefully, you found this useful.